# In Python, using concatenation inside open()

Tags: python, string, text, concatenation

I'm wondering how to combine the items inside of the open() function to end in:

```
FieldFile = open(r'C:\Users\Data1.txt')
```

So, in the context of having the following code and wanting to open the contents of "File1" and name the contents "FieldFile":

```
File1 = r'C:\Users\Data1.txt'
File2 = r'C:\Users\Data2.txt'
File3 = r'C:\Users\Data3.txt'
PointID = '1'

FieldFile = open('File' + PointID)
```

'File' and PointID are both text strings it looks like to me, therefore:

```
print 'File' + PointID
```

yields

```
File1
```

which has been set to:

```
File1 = r'C:\Users\Data1.txt'
```

So why doesn't the code snippet open 'File1' if I am basically doing the following?

```
FieldFile = open(File1)
```

Comment: are you missing the file extension? .txt?

Comment: `open(File1)` and `open('File1')` aren't the same thing. It looks like you should be using a list instead of numbered variables. Past like 2 of them, numbered variables are almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"File1"` is not the same thing as `File1`.  The first is a string; the second is the name of a variable.  You *could* use `eval("File" + PointID)` to get the value of `File1`, but it's better to do this:

```
path = r"C:\Users\Data{}.txt"
field_file = open(path.format(PointID))
```

Comment: In the context of the actual code that I already have, open(eval('File' + PointID)) is probably the easiest for me to use. Thanks!

Comment: @user2357112: Oops.  I forgot about that.  I have deleted that comment.

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping your filenames in a list?

```
FileNames = [r'C:\Users\Data1.txt', 
             r'C:\Users\Data2.txt',
             r'C:\Users\Data3.txt']
PointID = 1
```

Then you can access them by index:

```
FieldFile = open(FileNames[PointID - 1])
```

Note that the index has to start at 0, so to keep your PointID variable in sync with your filenames, you'll need to use PointID - 1 in the loop if you start it at 1.

If you want to avoid the PointID altogether, you can iterate over your FileName list like this:

```
for file_name in FileNames:
    FieldFile = open(file_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

*"So why doesn't the code snippet open 'File1'"*

Because data and code are inherently two different things. To cross the boundary and turn data into code, you use functions such as `eval()` and `exec()` - or, that is, you don't unless there's no other way. `eval`ing is messy and can cause security issues. Imagine what would happen if someone managed to sneak a string into your script that's actually a dangerous command. Your script could potentially turn that string into code and execute it... If you have to use `eval()`, you can often do as @zondo suggested and use the safer `ast.literal_eval()` instead (it will only turn values into variables, not complex commands like `subprocess.call(["delete_my_harddrive"]`).

In your case, you probably don't *have* to turn `File1` into code but could instead view it as a key/value pair. `File1` is the key and `r'C:\Users\Data1.txt'` is the value. Which data type supports this concept? A dictionary!

```
files = {'File1':r'C:\Users\Data1.txt', 'File2':r'C:\Users\Data2.txt','File3':r'C:\Users\Data3.txt' }
open(files['File1'])
```

Doing something along these lines will allow you to keep the "variable" names (they're keys, not variables) and associates the file paths with the individual keys.

Comment: Thanks @jDo, this clarifies the actual issue for me. Someone did suggest using a dictionary earlier, but my list of files will actually only be 2 items long for now (rather than 3 which I have shown now). Perhaps I will have a reason to use dictionaries in the future once I have more files.

Comment: @AF2k15 You're welcome. The advantage of a dictionary over a list - in this case - is the ability to denote your files by name rather than by index. To me at least,`files['File1']` is more explicit than `file_list[1]` (which file was number 1 again?). Also, if you don't need a fixed order (which lists provide), a dictionary is faster and more efficient since it's internally a hash map.